# Mac OS: How to use RSYNC to copy files modified within the last 24 hours and keep folder structure?

Tags: rsync

It's a simple question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm on a Mac with Big Sur with all the latest updates, and I'm going through Terminal to get these commands to run. If there's a better way please let me know.

This is, in basic terms, what I'm trying to do--I want RSYNC to recursively go through a source directory (which in this case would ideally be an entire drive), find any files modified within the last 24 hours, and copy those to another drive, while preserving the folder structure. So if I have:

```
/Volumes/Drive1/Folder1/File1.file
/Volumes/Drive1/Folder1/File2.file
/Volumes/Drive1/Folder1/File3.file
```

And File1 has been modified in the last 24 hours, but the other two haven't, I want it to copy that file, so that on the second drive I wind up with:

```
/Volumes/Drive2/Folder1/File1.file
```

But without copying File2 and File3.

I've tried a lot of different solutions and strings, but I'm running into problems. The closest I've been able to get is this:

```
find /Volumes/Drive1/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp -a "{}" /Volumes/Drive2/ \;
```

The problem is that while this one does go through Drive1 and find all the files newer than a day like I want, when it copies them it just dumps them all into the root of Drive2.

This one also seems to come close:

```
rsync --progress --files-from=<(find /Volumes/Drive1/ -mtime -1 -type f -exec basename {} \;) /Volumes/Drive1/ /Volumes/Drive2/
```

This one also identifies all the files modified in the last 24 hours, but instead of copying them it gives an error, "link_stat (filename and path) failed: no such file or directory (2)."

I've spent several days trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I can't figure it out. Help please!

Comment: Do you want to copy the *entire* folder structure, or just the parts that contain recent files?

Comment: Ideally I'd just like the parts that contain recent files, but I could live with duplicating the whole folder structure if it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work:

```
srcDir=/Volumes/Drive1
destDir=/Volumes/Drive2
(cd "$srcDir" && find . -type f -mtime -1 -print0) |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filepath; do
        mkdir -p "$(dirname "$destDir/$filepath")"
        cp -a "$srcDir/$filepath" "$destDir/$filepath"
    done
```

Explanation:

- Using `cd "$srcDir"; find . -whatever` will generate *relative paths* (starting with "./") from the source directory to the found files; that means appending the results to `$srcDir` and `$destDir` will give the full source and destination paths for each file.

  Putting it in parentheses makes it run in a subshell, so the `cd` won't affect other commands. Coupling `cd` and `find` with `&&` means that if `cd` fails, it won't run `find` (which would run in the wrong place, generate a list of the wrong file file, and generally cause trouble).
- Using `-print0` and `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'` is a standard weird-filename-safe way of iterating over found files (see [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)). Note that if anything in the loop reads from standard input (e.g. `cp -i` asking for confirmation), it'll steal part of the file list; if this is a worry, use this variant (instead of the pipe) to send the file list over file descriptor #3 instead of standard input:

  ```
   while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filepath <&3; do
       ...
   done 3< <(cd "$srcDir" && find . -type f -mtime -1 -print0)
  ```
- Finally, `mkdir -p` is used to make sure the destination directory exists, and then `cp` to copy the file.

Comment: Thank you! I won't be able to try this out until Friday but I'll follow up with what happens.

One question--what do you mean it'll "steal part of the file list"? (I'll be the first to admit I'm much more familiar with Powershell than with anything in the Mac realm)

Comment: When piping to a `while read` loop like this, you're piping input to the `read` command *and everything else in the loop*, so if anything else in the loop reads input, it'll get part of the file list. See [BashFAQ #89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) for some extreme examples.

Comment: It works like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks. Only one question left--I do kind of miss the verbose output from RSync, is there a way to get a verbose output with a CP command?

Comment: @tnpir4002 Yes, you could either use `cp -v` (which might be *too* verbose), or add your own reporting with something like `echo "Copying $filepath" >&2` (the `>&2` sends output to stderr rather than stdout, which is generally best for status/progress messages as well as real errors).